# Hiding a value after a , (comma) ($value = 53,523412 to become > 53,5)

Tags: php

So in my database, there are users with 13532345 credits. for example

```
<?php 
  $million = $userstats['13532345'] /1000000;
  echo $million; 
?> Millions
```

The value comes out as 13.532345 millions, but what i want it to be is 13.5 millions. So how do you hide the rest of the value?

```
<?php 
  echo $userstats['username']; 
  $million = $userstats['credits'] /1000000; 
?>
<a href="##" class="link">
   <?php echo $million; ?> Millions
</a>
```

Comment: take a look at  e.g. round()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used the [number_format();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
$million=13.532345;
echo  number_format((float)$million, 1, '.', '');
//output=13.5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function.

```
echo round($million, 1);
```

or the [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function.

```
echo number_format ( $million, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) for that.

Here's snippet from linked documentation:

```
echo round(3.4);         // 3
echo round(3.5);         // 4
echo round(3.6);         // 4
echo round(3.6, 0);      // 4
echo round(1.95583, 2);  // 1.96
echo round(1241757, -3); // 1242000
echo round(5.045, 2);    // 5.05
echo round(5.055, 2);    // 5.06
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by -

```
substr($million, 0, 4); // will return first four characters
```

or use round it up

```
round($million, 1);
```

or format it -

```
number_format($million, 1, ',', ' ');
```